# Python / Regex: exclude everything except one thing

Tags: python, regex

Suppose I have these strings:

```
a = "hello"
b = "-hello"
c = "-"
d = "hell-o"
e = "    - "
```

How do I match only the `-`(String `C`)? I've tried a `if "-" in something` but obviously that isn't correct. Could someone please advise?

---

Let's say we put these strings into a list, looped through and all I wanted to extract was `C`. How would I do this?

```
for aa in list1:
    if not re.findall('[^-$]'):
        print aa
```

Would that be *too* messy?

Comment: How is that not correct?

Comment: What do you mean by “match”? `"-" in "-"` surely evaluates to *True*.

Comment: @theEconomist: don't use `list` for variable name: it shadows built-in.

Comment: @Anthony: this is absolutely wrong and ridiculous regex. It might not *look* messy, but it certainly **is**.

Comment: He messes it up because he used []

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to match only variable `c`:

```
if '-' == something:
   print 'hurray!'
```

To answer the updates: yes, that would be too messy. You don't need regex there. Simple string methods are faster:

```
>>> lst =["hello", "-hello", "-", "hell-o","    - "]
>>> for i, item in enumerate(lst):
    if item == '-':
        print(i, item)


2 -
```

Comment: Also using convention `if "-" in list` will *only* match the `-` and not `<spaces here>-`

Answer (score 1):

as a regex its "^-$"

Comment: Character ranges are only recognized in character classes (`[…]`). `a-z` does only match `a-z` and not any character in the range of `a`–`z`.

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is strip out the dash (i.e. `he-llo` gives `hello`), then this is more of a job for generator expressions.

```
''.join((char for char in 'he-llo' if char != '-'))
```

Comment: If all those values were in a list, he would want to return the variable that holds the string he's matching, `-` so he would want `c` to be found or returned.

Answer (score 0):

```
if "-" in c and len(c) ==1 : print "do something"
```

OR

```
if c=="-"
```